# Como utilizar fontes customizadas no React?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou recebendo o seguinte `error`:

```
TypeError:name.includes is not a function
```

Este `error` ocorre quando adiciono o seguinte trecho de código:

```
fontFamily: fonts.regular
```

**App.js**

```js
const fontConfig = {
  default: {
    regular: {
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",
      fontWeight: "normal"
    },
    medium: {
      fontFamily: "sans-serif-medium",
      fontWeight: "normal"
    },
    light: {
      fontFamily: "sans-serif-light",
      fontWeight: "normal"
    },
    thin: {
      fontFamily: "sans-serif-thin",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }
  }
};

const theme = {
  ...DarkTheme,
  fonts: configureFonts(fontConfig),
  dark: true
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <FirstScreen />
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

FirstScreen code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { withTheme } from "react-native-paper";

const FirstScreen = props => {
  const { colors, fonts } = props.theme;

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: colors.background
      }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          color: colors.primary,
          fontFamily: fonts.regular
        }}
      >
        Oi mundo
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default withTheme(FirstScreen);
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow **in Portuguese**. As the name implies, the official language used here is Portuguese. So, can you please translate your question? If you prefer, you may also ask this same question in [the English StackOverflow site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

Isto depende de como você está estilizando o seu projeto, geralmente para quem realmente entende o conceito do react utiliza-se o `styled-components`.

Logo sabendo-se disto eu irei dar dois exemplos de como utilizar a fonte customizada levando em consideração que você possua certo nível de conhecimento no react, segue os exemplos:

**1) Utilizando `@import`**

Geralmente para a estruturação correta das pastas, é feito o seguinte:

```
src/styles/Fonts.js e src/styles/Global.js
```

**Fonts.js**

```
import { css } from 'styled-components';

const RobotoFont = css`
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
`;

export default RobotoFont;
```

**Global.js**

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  ${RobotoFont}
  body {
    font: 1rem Roboto, sans-serif;
  }
`;

export default GlobalStyle;
```

**2) Utilizando `@font-face`**
Geralmente para a estruturação correta das pastas, é feito o seguinte:

```
src/styles/Fonts.js, src/styles/Global.js e src/assets/fonts
```

**Fonts.js**

```
import { css } from "styled-components";

// FONT ICON'S
import {
  SpotifyEOT,
  SpotifyTTF,
  SpotifyWOFF,
  SpotifySVG,
  CircularLightEOT,
  CircularLightTTF,
  CircularLightWOFF,
  CircularLightWOFF2,
  CircularLightSVG,
  CircularBookEOT,
  CircularBookTTF,
  CircularBookWOFF,
  CircularBookWOFF2,
  CircularBookSVG,
  CircularBoldEOT,
  CircularBoldTTF,
  CircularBoldWOFF,
  CircularBoldWOFF2,
  CircularBoldSVG
} from "assets/fonts";

export const IconFontFace = css`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'spotify';
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url('${SpotifyEOT}?vvuwob');
        src: url('${SpotifyEOT}?vvuwob#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('${SpotifyTTF}?vvuwob') format('truetype'),
             url('${SpotifyWOFF}?vvuwob') format('woff'),
             url('${SpotifySVG}?vvuwob#spotify') format('svg');
    }
`;

export const MainFontFace = css`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Circular-Light';
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url('${CircularLightEOT}');
        src: url('${CircularLightEOT}') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('${CircularLightTTF}') format('truetype'),
             url('${CircularLightWOFF}') format('woff2'),
             url('${CircularLightWOFF2}') format('woff'),
             url('${CircularLightSVG}') format('svg');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Circular-Book';
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url('${CircularBookEOT}');
        src: url('${CircularBookEOT}') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('${CircularBookTTF}') format('truetype'),
             url('${CircularBookWOFF}') format('woff2'),
             url('${CircularBookWOFF2}') format('woff'),
             url('${CircularBookSVG}') format('svg');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Circular-Bold';
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url('${CircularBoldEOT}');
        src: url('${CircularBoldEOT}') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('${CircularBoldTTF}') format('truetype'),
             url('${CircularBoldWOFF}') format('woff2'),
             url('${CircularBoldWOFF2}') format('woff'),
             url('${CircularBoldSVG}') format('svg');
    }
`;
```

**Global.js**

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

// FONTS
import { MainFontFace } from "./Fonts";

// OTHERS
import Color from "./Colors";

const Themes = {
  default: {
    color: Color.greyLight2,
    background: Color.black2
  },
  midnight: {
    color: Color.greyBlack2,
    background: `linear-gradient(to right, ${
      Color.greyBlack2
    }, black), linear-gradient(transparent, black 70%)`
  },
  error: {
    color: "white",
    background: `linear-gradient(85deg, ${Color.red}, ${Color.orange} 60%)`
  }
};

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    ${MainFontFace};
    body {
        font-family: 'Circular-Light', 'Circular-Book', 'Circular-Bold', sans-serif;
    }
`;

GlobalStyle.defaultProps = {
  theme: "default"
};


export default GlobalStyle;
```

Logo em src/assets/fonts repare que temos uma outra pasta dentro desta hierarquia denominada `src/assets/fonts/circular` e um arquivo denominado `src/assets/fonts/index.js`. O qual local `src/assets/fonts` contém os arquivos das fontes (`ttf`, `eot` e etc..), logo o arquivo `index.js` eu fiz uma técnica denominada "`barrel`", que nada mais é uma técnica de exportação, para facilitar a nossa vida nos imports.

**Index.js**

```
// BARREL ICON'S FONT'S
export { default as SpotifyEOT } from "assets/fonts/icons/spotify.eot";
export { default as SpotifyTTF } from "assets/fonts/icons/spotify.ttf";
export { default as SpotifyWOFF } from "assets/fonts/icons/spotify.woff";
export { default as SpotifySVG } from "assets/fonts/icons/spotify.svg";

// BARREL MAIN FONT'S

// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularLightEOT } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Light.eot";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularLightTTF } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Light.ttf";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularLightWOFF } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Light.woff";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularLightWOFF2 } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Light.woff2";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularLightSVG } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Light.svg";

// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularBookEOT } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Book.eot";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularBookTTF } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Book.ttf";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularBookWOFF } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Book.woff";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularBookWOFF2 } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Book.woff2";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularBookSVG } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Book.svg";

// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularBoldEOT } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Bold.eot";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularBoldTTF } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Bold.ttf";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularBoldWOFF } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Bold.woff";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularBoldWOFF2 } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Bold.woff2";
// prettier-ignore
export { default as CircularBoldSVG } from "assets/fonts/circular/CircularSpUIv3T-Bold.svg";
```

Você pode acessar o meu github, lá eu possuo diversos repositórios em reactjs com uma ótima estruturação de pastas e clean code. [CLIQUE AQUI PARA ACESSAR](https://github.com/thiagodebonisoficial).